# Java program that does simple string manipulations is not working

Tags: java

I have to do a java lab that will take an inputted sentence and create a new string with only the words beginning with vowels.

Example:

> input:    It is a hot and humid summer day.
>
> output:   Itisaand.

EDIT: The output I get is anananananan.

Here's my code (with comments).  The methods are pretty simple.  Im just not sure why this isn't working.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String input = console.nextLine();
        Class strings = new Class(input);
        // class has constructor for input
        int beg = 0, end = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
            if (strings.isVowel(j) && (input.charAt(j - 1) == ' ' || j == 0))
                beg = j;
            // isVowel finds if there is a vowel at the location
            else if (strings.endWord(j))
                end = j - 1;
            // endWord finds if there is a space or punctuation at the location

            if (beg == end - 2)
                strings.findWord(beg, end);
            // findWord adds a substring of input from beg to end to the answer
        }
        System.out.print("\nOutput: ");
        strings.printAnswer();
        // printAnswer prints the answer
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the code for my class.

```
public class Class {

    String input = "", answer = "";

    public Class(String input1) {
        input = input1;
    }

    public boolean isVowel(int loc) {
        return (input.charAt(loc) == 'a' || input.charAt(loc) == 'e' || input.charAt(loc) == 'i'
                || input.charAt(loc) == 'o' || input.charAt(loc) == 'u');
    }

    public boolean endWord(int loc) {
        return (input.charAt(loc) == ' ' || input.charAt(loc) == '.' || input.charAt(loc) == '?'
                || input.charAt(loc) == '!');
    }

    public void findWord(int beg, int end) {
        answer = answer + (input.substring(beg, end));
    }

    public void printAnswer() {
        System.out.println(answer + ".");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the expected output, but what is your *actual* output?

Comment: Hi Anthony, welcome to stack overflow. I suggest that you read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting next time (title) and no need to thank users in advance :)

Comment: is `Class` your own class? If so, add it to the `import` on top as it can be confused with `java.lang.Class`

Comment: @IvayloSlavov An `import` isn't required if they're in the same package, which is likely the case here (if it is a custom class they've written).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, you have a point, still it is confsuing a little. At least, I did not understand if the application did fail, or did not output correctly

Comment: debug will solve your problem

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Class` class?

Comment: I did write the class.  It's in the same package.  The import at the top is for the scanner class used for user input.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems, but the most immediate issue with the logic is this part:

```
if(beg==end-2)
    strings.findWord(beg, end);
```

That will only recognise two character words, so wouldn't match "a" or "and" even though they're valid.

Answer (score 0):

`input.charAt(j - 1)` will throw [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) when `j` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I will not write the java code for you but will give you logical steps to follow.

```
while(true)
    start = input.indexOf(" ")
    if(start == -1)
        break
    end = input.index of(" ", start)
    if(end == -1)
        word = input.substr(start, input.length-1)
    else
        word = input.substr(start, end)
    if first letter of word is a vowel
        save it
    if(end == -1)
        break
```

Your logic is absolutely right, but not the best way of going about to fixing the problem

EDIT:

For you however solution is simple.

You can do

```
if(beg < end)
```

And everything will work.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this but for the assignment we need to use the methods I wrote in the class.  This does seem like the logical way to do it but that's not the assignment.

Comment: I made this change to the code and now my output is:
Iia hoananananananand humiand humiand humiand humiand humiand humiand humiand humid summeand humid summeand humid summeand humid summeand humid summer da.